# Extract helix residues from DSSP with awk

Tags: awk, bioinformatics

I would like to extract helix(H) residues from  DSSP files .

**1CRN.dssp**

```
 31   37 A K  H   < S+
 32   38 A V  H  < S+ 
 33   39 A F  H >< S- 
 34   40 A G  G >< S+ 
 35   41 A K  G >  S+
```

**1GB5.dssp**

```
113  242 B G  H 3>>S+
114  243 B I  H <45S+    
115  244 B L  H X45S+     
116  245 B S  H 3<5S+ 
117  246 B K  T >X5S+
```

I want to save the output in the following format.

```
>1CRN
KVF
>1GB5
GILS
```

How can I do this with awk? Your suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the 'H' in the 5 th column that indicates "helix(H) residues"?

```
awk '{
  if (FNR == 1 ) print ">" FILENAME  
  if ($5 == "H") {
    printf $4
  }
} 
END { printf "\n"}'  file
```

**output**

```
>tstDat.txt
KVF
```

IHTH

Comment: The `if` clauses could be conditions for two separate blocks, e.g.: `FNR == 1 { print ">" FILENAME }` etc.

Comment: @Thor : yes, agreed. I'm aware (and personally use) idomatic awk blocks, but I think for people that don't understand awk, the implied while loop (on each record) is enough to take in on a first solution. Good luck to all.